# apt and apt-get are corrupt. How to reinstall?

Tags: 16.04, apt

If I am not mistaken I tried to upgrade apt to a higher version quite a while ago, but that didn't work out.
I did however try to run `apt get` again, but now apt fails.

```
apt: symbol lookup error: apt: undefined symbol: _ZN11CommandLine10GetCommandEPKNS_8DispatchEjPKPKc


apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN11CommandLine10GetCommandEPKNS_8DispatchEjPKPKc
```

This breaks my letsencrypt update script, and basically frustrating.
I was looking online but all I find is more and more dependencies that fail to install due to other dependencies mismatches, and an overall of `404 file not found` on the web for these packages. 
I am not an expert but I did understand that maybe using wget, dpkg may be of some use.

This is how my days look now:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for teddy:
(Reading database ... 81475 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.2.29ubuntu0.1) over (1.0.1ubuntu2.24) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.2.29ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 on system is 1.2.29.
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

I have no idea how to completely revert back to my original apt version just to make things work back again.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your original apt package should be in stored locally in /var/cache/apt/archives...unless you deleted it.

Comment: it is there! Thanks! But now what? 
ls | grep apt  
apt-transport-https_1.2.24_amd64.deb  
apt-transport-https_1.2.29_amd64.deb  
apt-utils_1.2.24_amd64.deb  
apt-utils_1.2.29_amd64.deb  
apt_1.2.24_amd64.deb  
apt_1.2.29_amd64.deb  
libapt-inst2.0_1.2.24_amd64.deb  
libapt-inst2.0_1.2.29_amd64.deb  
libapt-pkg5.0_1.2.24_amd64.deb  
libapt-pkg5.0_1.2.29_amd64.deb  
python-apt-common_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb  
python3-apt_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb

Comment: I tried dpkg -i on some of these packages, but they won't install due to some other dependencies.

Comment: trying to install the oldest versions won't succeed

Comment: sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.24_amd64.deb ==>


dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.2.24); however:
  Package libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...

Comment: When using dpkg, you must install dependencies first (dpkg won't do that for you). The sequence of which package goes first, second, third, etc. matters. Your error message indicated that you have dependency packages that are not configured yet - configure them. Dpkg rewards folks who parse it's output carefully.

Comment: Thanks @user535733! Thanks to that archive apt works back again! spread the love!